# Kaspersky antivirus blocking Visual Studio stable build download for windows

Tags: visual-studio, download, antivirus, blocked, kaspersky

### Summary: Kasperysky is not allowing to download the Visual Studio for windows.

**Platform details**:

- OS: Windows 10
- Browser: Chrome
- Browser Extension: Kaspersky protection

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Launch [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
2. Click on "Download for Windows" button
3. User will be redirected to [Thanks for downloading VS Code for Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=win)

After 3rd step we will be blocked by Kaspersky antivirus saying that "Visiting a dangerous website has been prevented" (see below image)

> Actual dangerous web address which is getting blocked: https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/6cba118ac49a1b88332f312a8f67186f7f3c1643/VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.61.2.exe

*Any reason why Visual Studio download web address is showing as dangerous and totally blocking us from downloading it? Is it safe to bypass and download it? Or, any other known issues which I am unaware of?*

### **Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Only the antivirus vendor or Microsoft can give you an answer. Such questions should be sent to the vendors directly.

Comment: Sure, I will try to post on their forums. Thanks.

Comment: Posted same query to [Kaspersky community forum](https://community.kaspersky.com/kaspersky-total-security-14/kaspersky-antivirus-blocking-visual-studio-stable-build-download-for-windows-21061). Once I receive any answer from them will share the solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

That's possibly due to a fake link in an ad, or something similar. It's pretty common and I often get alerts from Avast that it blocked URL:Blacklist threats via its Web Shield, too. I wasn't testing the reproduction, but...

If this happens again when you restart the Thank You page, I would recommend you temporarily turning off the Kaspersky extension until the file is installed and the tab is closed.

If you're using Kaspersky as your antivirus too, and it detects VS as malware, report this as a false positive (if you're sure it is a false positive) and create an exception.

Think that should resolve your problem.